# How do I setup a SAP Fiori Launchpad plugin?

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I need to set up a Fiori Launchpad plugin to be able to increase the session timeout.

I've followed the instructions here:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/webide-flpextensibility/ee0e48567c034991ac079eb93348d3b2.html

But I get the following error:

> 4:38:10 PM (FioriRunner) Failed to run the application with extenders

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you enable SAP Fiori Launchpad Extensibility in extensions?

Comment: Yes. That gave me the option to create an app of that type. It wont run or deploy to SCP. That's the problem.

Comment: I've now deployed to SAP Cloud Platform and it works in the Sandbox Launchpad.

However, when I come to add the plugin app to our Portal Fiori Launchpad. The App isn't there to be added...

I get the error.

"severity": "Info", "text": "No replication for HTML5 app 'shelltimeout' needed because it's still on already fully replicated active version 1.0.19", "key": "HTML5AppReplicator.replicationNotNeeded", "params": [ "shelltimeout", "1.0.19" ] },